# Using RegExReplace correctly

Tags: autohotkey

I'm having trouble getting RegExReplace to work correctly.

My input:

```
COW MOO OPTION:
test1|test2|test3||
test4|test5|test6||
CHICKEN WING:
test7|test8|test9|test10|test11|test12|test13|test14||test15||||test16|test17||
test18|test19|test20|||test21|test22|test23|test24|test25||
```

My RegExReplace:
`input := RegExReplace(input, "^(\w*\s?)*:$", "")`

From my understanding this should remove text similar to `COW MOO OPTION:` or `CHICKEN WING:` however when I use `MsgBox` to view the input I still see the text.

I wish this type of text to be removed, how can this be done?

EDIT:
I think I'm going to go with a `Loop, Parse,` on a newline.

```
inquiryRequest := clipboard
Loop, parse, inquiryRequest, `n
{
  if instr(A_LoopField, "|")
    result := result . A_LoopField . "`n"
}
```

But I'm still not sure why the `RegExReplace` didn't work?

Comment: Your regex itself seems fine. I tested it in my code editor and it finds both of your target strings. Maybe something about the way RegExReplace works? Try just using a very simple haystack and needle and see if the function really returns the value you expect.

Comment: Can you provide an example with actual data you want to parse? Regex seems a bit overkill in this case. Here, you could just loop over each line and check if there's a `:`. Since you don't seem to be interested in the actual content of these "headlines", you certainly don't need to match them. Bottom line: If there won't be any colons in the list you're trying to retrieve, simly dismiss those which do contain one.

Comment: Addendum: [This example](http://pastebin.com/4CqVwnGh) shows what I meant.

Comment: @GreatBigBor, I'm not sure what you mean, `inStr` the resulting string? this still finds the colon.                                                         @MCL, I like your solution but I cannot say for sure that `:` won't be in the data and that's why I was thinking `RegExReplace`, but was hopping for a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Loop Parse, in a similar way to what MCL suggested only instead of looking for `:`'s I looked for `|`'s since I know they will always been in a line I want.

```
inquiryRequest := clipboard
Loop, parse, inquiryRequest, `n
{
  if instr(A_LoopField, "|")
    result := result . A_LoopField . "`n"
}
```